# How can I remove a footer from specific cms page?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.0, magento-2.1.3

Can I remove footer from a cms page ? and I added that page using admin panel .

```
default.xml  file 


<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Infortis. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

    <body>

        <!-- <move name="breadcrumbs" destination="mycustom.div" before="-" /> -->
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-downloadable-products-link" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-newsletter-subscriptions-link" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-billing-agreements-link" remove="true"/>

        <move element="customer-account-navigation-orders-link" destination="customer_account_navigation" before="customer-account-navigation-address-link"/>
        <move element="customer-account-navigation-wish-list-link" destination="customer_account_navigation" after="customer-account-navigation-address-link"/>
        <move element="customer-account-navigation-my-credit-cards-link" destination="customer_account_navigation" after="customer-account-navigation-product-reviews-link"/>

        <referenceBlock name="base-footer-container">

            <!-- Static blocks -->
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="block_footer_links_sec">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">block_footer_links_sec</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="block_footer_social_section">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">block_footer_social_section</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="block_footer_brands_banner">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">block_footer_brands_banner</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="block_footer_end_liner">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">block_footer_end_liner</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="block_footer_candidio_sec">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">block_footer_candidio_sec</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>

    </body>

</page>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add below code in your **CMS page > Design > Layout Update XML**

```
<referenceContainer name="footer-container" remove="true" />
```

Clear Cache. It will remove Footer from Specific CMS page where you add above code.

Comment: This should work, was just about to post this solution.

Comment: @AbhishekPanchal  I don't know why this is not working , I  have cleared cache aswell. I think footer has been added custom. So where I can check its referenceContainer  name?

Comment: You can check footer name in ‘Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml’

Comment: I attached default.xml . and I just wanted to remove that block    block_footer_candidio_sec . how Can I ?

Comment: for Complete header ??

Answer (score 3):

In backend, Content -> Pages -> Edit the right page -> tab "Design", field "Layout Update XML".

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <referenceBlock name="block_footer_candidio_sec" remove="true" />
</referenceContainer>
```

Write me if you have any issues.

Comment: no its not working :(

Comment: Did you clear a cache?

Comment: I don't know why this is not working , I have cleared cache aswell. I think footer has been added custom. So where I can check its referenceContainer name?

Comment: Could you show me `Theme_Root/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`? You can use https://pastebin.com service for post whole file

Comment: done , I want to remove  '  block_footer_candidio_sec'    . check updated question. thank you

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: still not helping   http://52.11.243.166/social-gallery   . I think its not reference block . its just a block.

Comment: Check my answer again, please, I updated it

Comment: Still not . is it a possibility that  xml is not working on admin side ? :(

Comment: when I do    <referenceBlock  name="base-footer-container"  remove="true" />      it remove all data . but I want just that candid-sec to remove